# Can Process.Start(...) use a stream as input instead of a file?

Tags: vb.net, stream, process.start

I'm creating (from scratch, not from existing files) PDF files in memory for storage in an SQL Server database. To open one such PDF file for viewing with the default PDF handler, I first have to write the PDF file from memory to a temporary location on disk and then call Process.Start(filePath). When done with viewing, I have to delete the temporary file.

Although this works fine, I'd like to skip the step of writing from memory to disk (and after viewing having to delete the temporary file), but use the PDF file in memory to create a stream and use this stream as input for Process.Start(...).

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: `Process.Start` is basically equivalent to typing a commandline into a console window.  If you can't do it with a comandline in a console window, you can't do it using `Process.Start` either.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your insights. Obvious, although not satisfying...

Comment: *"Obvious, although not satisfying"*.  I'm often described that way.